# Increase the indentation after date specifications in Badge pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, design

The indentation after the date specifications in pages like "Nice/Good/Great Question Badge" is somewhat too small, so that date specifications including (previous) years nearly touch or overlap the question titles. The effect varies between different Stack Exchange sites. Here's a (not too bad) [example from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question?userid=1):

[image]

And a more problematic [example from tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/20/nice-question?userid=575):

[image]

Please increase the indentation so that longer date specifications do not touch/overlap the question/answer titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new design of badge pages introduced in June 2013, the more problematic touches/overlaps [are gone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question?userid=575).

[image]